# Compare from and to date angularJs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have to show error message next to the control when ToDate is before than From Date, currently I have added min date which helps in disabling the To date before from date but its not doing anything if the To date value is untouched. It should show some error when from date is after To date.

Example added on Plunk. http://plnkr.co/edit/SN9QwK5nKuNdNiRYLMhH?p=preview&preview

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerPopupDemoCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.datePicker = {};
    $scope.start = new Date();
    $scope.end = new Date();

    $scope.datePicker.minStartDate = new Date();
    // $scope.datePicker.maxStartDate = $scope.end; 
    $scope.datePicker.minEndDate = $scope.start;
    //   $scope.datePicker.maxEndDate = $scope.end; //fixed date same as $scope.maxStartDate init value

    // watcher to watch the "From" date and set the min date for 'To' datepicker 
    $scope.$watch('start', function(v) {
        $scope.datePicker.minEndDate = v;
        $scope.dateOptions2.minDate = v;
    });


    $scope.dateOptions1 = {
        //dateDisabled: disabled,
        formatYear: 'yyyy',
        //  maxDate: $scope.datePicker.maxStartDate,
        minDate: $scope.datePicker.minStartDate,
        startingDay: 1
    };

    $scope.dateOptions2 = {
        //dateDisabled: disabled,
        formatYear: 'yyyy',
        //  maxDate: $scope.datePicker.maxEndDate,
        minDate: $scope.datePicker.minEndDate,
        startingDay: 1
    };
    // Disable weekend selection
    function disabled(data) {
        var date = data.date,
            mode = data.mode;
        return mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
    }
    $scope.open1 = function() {
        $scope.popup1.opened = true;
    };

    $scope.open2 = function() {
        $scope.popup2.opened = true;
    };

    $scope.formats = ['dd.MM.yyyy'];
    $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
    $scope.altInputFormats = ['M!/d!/yyyy'];

    $scope.popup1 = {
        opened: false
    };

    $scope.popup2 = {
        opened: false
    };

});
```

HTML

```
div ng-controller="DatepickerPopupDemoCtrl">
    <h5>From Date</h5>
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" 
                  class="form-control" 
                  uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" 
                  ng-model="start" 
                  is-open="popup1.opened" 
                  datepicker-options="dateOptions1" 
                  close-text="Close" 
                  readonly="true" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
            </button>
          </span>
        </p>

        <hr>
      <h5>To Date</h5>
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" 
                  class="form-control" 
                  uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" 
                  ng-model="end" 
                  is-open="popup2.opened" 
                  datepicker-options="dateOptions2" 
                  close-text="Close" 
                  readonly="true"/>
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
            </button>
          </span>
        </p>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `getTime()` on the calendar ng-model variable to compare numbers

```
$scope.$watch('start', function(v) {
        $scope.datePicker.minEndDate = v;
        $scope.dateOptions2.minDate = v;

        let toIsBeforeFrom = new Date($scope.start).getTime() - new Date($scope.end).getTime() >1

    });
```